# Why do the same Wine applications appear in applications list many times? How to fix this?

Tags: wine

Why are there 4 IEs (I have not installed them manually, may be one, but not four), 2 WordPads, 2 "winebrowsers" (and 2 notepads there up the list)? Do you know how fix this correctly?

[image: Wine apps suplicates]

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Yi Jiang's question is about removed Wine applications while I've never removed any, and mostly even never installed - these dupes are there out-of-the-box. None of these applications can be found in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: This has been reopened

Answer (score 3):

- Launch Menu editor from the dash.

[image]

- Go to the Other Category.

[image]

- Remove all the useless or duplicated shortcuts.

[image]

- Done!