# Why do applications duplicates appear in menus?

Tags: appmenu

In all the places where applications are listed, duplicates of some of them may appear. Why? Below are some examples:

[image: ClassicMenu indicator]
[image: "Open with" menu]
[image: "Select application" dialogue]

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30206/why-do-the-same-wine-applications-appear-in-applications-list-many-times-how-to) is an old question of mine that can be considered related. It's about Wine apps only (native Linux apps were not duplicating during those days) and I doubt the reason is the same as Wine is "quite a different opera". I was also not able to find the "Main Menu" app mentioned in the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely that's because there are multiple `.desktop` files for those applications in `/usr/share/applications/` or `$HOME/.local/share/applications/`.

To get the "Main Menu" app install the package `alacarte`.

Comment: Funny (well, not really) thing, the classic menu indicator (which I assume you are the author of, and that's why I adore you) has gone empty (all the apps disappeared, only Personal, Hardware, System and ClassicMenu Indicator submenus left) as soon as I have visited both directories you have mentioned with an elevated mc (not deleted/changed anything, everything is still there intact) and installed alacarte (not even launched it). Restarting the indicator doesn't help.

Comment: Now as I have launched Alacarte all the apps are there (including the duplicates) but not in the ClassicMenu indicator menu.

Comment: Everything works just fine as I have restarted the system. Still curious what it was...

Comment: Which version of ClassicMenu indicator are you using?

Comment: I was using the version included in the standard Ububti 15.10 repositories (as I like its look better - I prefer empty places instead of gears icons where no icon is defined). Now, as I have upgraded thinking it was going to fix the problem, I am using 0.09-1 from the PPA.

Comment: Another thing I don't like about the new version is it doesn't show Wine as a separate program group (puts it in "Other" instead) while the older version does.